# Summarize a Kusto Table based on max_count

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have data in large table as follows

[image]

I would like to summarize in the following manner in Kusto.  So in the above session A ends at PageId =5, session B ends at PageId=3, session C ends at PageId=2, session D ends at PageId=2. Hence the summarized table would be as below.

[image]

However, I am unable to figure out how to do it. Any tips on how to go about this - I tried summarize by maxif() but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you provide any explanation about how your output should be formed? `Sessions with Max_PageId`- How you want generate these values?

Comment: Sure, I added some clarification if that helps. Please let me know if it needs more detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this

```
let T = datatable(Session:string, PageId:long)
[
    "A", 1,
    "A", 2,
    "A", 3,
    "A", 4,
    "A", 5,
    "B", 1,
    "B", 2,
    "B", 3,
    "C", 1,
    "C", 2,
    "D", 1,
    "D", 2,
]
;
let session_ids = T | distinct PageId;
session_ids
| join kind=leftouter (
    T
    | summarize PageId = max(PageId) by Session
    | summarize count() by PageId
) on PageId
| extend count_ = coalesce(count_, 0)
| project PageId, count_
| order by PageId asc
```

| PageId | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 |